# display dashboard widgets per user type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to display dashboard based on user data and user type. I was able to display the dashboard based on the user data by filtering the queries on the user id.

currently our site has 2 user types: { normal, manager } and the types can be  increased later by adding for example : "admin" and "super user" and so on.

so far I am displaying the dashboard by the following:

```
@if(ViewBag.UserType =="manager")
{
    @Html.DashboardWidget("NumberOfEmployeesQuery")
    @Html.DashboardWidget("ContractThatWillExpiresSoonQuery")
    ....
} 
else if(ViewBag.UserType == "normal")
{
     ... display the widgets related to the normal users
}
```

As you can see, later if I want to add another `UserType` dashboard widget, I need to modify the view code which is not logic in my opinion and I should find a way to automate this task.

Is there way to avoid hard coding the `if.. else` statement and to make it dynamically?

Comment: any idea if there is another method?